# Get values from keys in JSON

Tags: python, json

I got the JSON below:

```json
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "category_id": "1960",
      "category_name": "England",
      "competitions": [
        {
          "competition_id": "222",
          "competition_name": "Premier League"
        },
        {
          "competition_id": "203",
          "competition_name": "League One"
        },
        {
          "competition_id": "167",
          "competition_name": "Championship"
        },
        {
          "competition_id": "204",
          "competition_name": "League Two"
        },
        {
          "competition_id": "307",
          "competition_name": "National League"
        },
        {
          "competition_id": "693",
          "competition_name": "FA Cup"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category_id": "2007",
      "category_name": "Spain",
      "competitions": [
        {
          "competition_id": "14482",
          "competition_name": "LaLiga"
        },
        {
          "competition_id": "14982",
          "competition_name": "LaLiga 2"
        },
        {
          "competition_id": "989",
          "competition_name": "Copa del Rey"
        },
        {
          "competition_id": "38756",
          "competition_name": "Primera Division RFEF"
        },
        {
          "competition_id": "19477",
          "competition_name": "Second Division B"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I loop through the json using python to get the values of `competition_id`? I have tried using a for loop but it's only giving competition id of premier league. Below is the code I wrote

```py
for key in categories:
    competitions = key['competitions']
    print(competitions)
for key in competitions:
    competition_id = key['competition_id']
    print(competition_id)
```

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: You need nested loops. The outer loop is for categories, the inner loop is for competitions.

Comment: try extraction from last child and then add up to loop through your list, please let us know what you have tried so far

Comment: the second loop should be nested inside the first loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Barmar said, you need to run your inner loop inside of your outer loop:

```py
for key in categories:
        competitions = key['competitions']
        print(competitions)
        for key in competitions:
                 competition_id = key['competition_id']
                 print(competition_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

`data.json` file content:

```
{"categories": [{
                    "category_id": "1960",
                    "category_name": "England",
                    "competitions": [{
                            "competition_id": "222",
                            "competition_name": "Premier League"
                        }, {
                            "competition_id": "203",
                            "competition_name": "League One"
                        }, {
                            "competition_id": "167",
                            "competition_name": "Championship"
                        }, {
                            "competition_id": "204",
                            "competition_name": "League Two"
                        }, {
                            "competition_id": "307",
                            "competition_name": "National League"
                        }, {
                            "competition_id": "693",
                            "competition_name": "FA Cup"
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "category_id": "2007",
                    "category_name": "Spain",
                    "competitions": [{
                            "competition_id": "14482",
                            "competition_name": "LaLiga"
                        }, {
                            "competition_id": "14982",
                            "competition_name": "LaLiga 2"
                        }, {
                            "competition_id": "989",
                            "competition_name": "Copa del Rey"
                        }, {
                            "competition_id": "38756",
                            "competition_name": "Primera Division RFEF"
                        }, {
                            "competition_id": "19477",
                            "competition_name": "Second Division B"
                        }
                    ]
                }]}
```

Possible solution is the following:

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    

for item in data['categories']:
    for i in item['competitions']:
        print(i['competition_id'])
```

Prints

```
222
203
167
204
307
693
14482
14982
989
38756
19477
```

Comment: This uses a 3rd party library that must be installed. Which is of course fine, but it is nice to note this in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with a one-line comprehension, too.

```py
ids = [comp.get("competition_id") for cat in your_dict.get("categories") for comp in cat.get("competitions")]
print(ids)
```

output:

```
['222', '203', '167', '204', '307', '693', '14482', '14982', '989', '38756', '19477']
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you looped through the first index of the array only.
To get it you can try this.

```
for category in data['categories']:
for competition in category['competitions']:
    print(competition['competition_id'])
```

If you wand to form some kind of sentence:
this one:

```
for category in data['categories']:
for competition in category['competitions']:
    print(
        f"{category['category_name']} {category['category_id']} {competition['competition_name']} {competition['competition_id']}")
```

Comment: This code won't work. Maybe it is a copy paste issue, but you'll need to indent something after the first `for` lines.